# Change the column type of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing huge amount of values. The data frame is as follows

```
> datedPf
            date ticker quantity
96828 2013-01-11    ABT      700
96829 2013-01-11    AMD     9600
96830 2013-01-11    AMG      600
96831 2013-01-11   AGCO      800
96832 2013-01-11      A     1300
etc...
```

The type of the "ticker" and "quantity" columns are `factor`. I found this using `class(datedPf$ticker)` and `class(datedPf$quantity)` respectively. But the type of the "date" column is `date`. I want to change that type to `factor`. How can I change this?

Comment: I think you should check using `class(datedPf$ticker)`, not `typeof`. It gives R's internal storage mode of the object

Comment: Did you try `datedPf$date <- as.factor( datedPf$date )`.

Comment: @Arun:please note the edit in the question

Comment: You can just do `str(datePf)` to see the structure (types) of your data

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`datedPf$date = as.factor(datePf$date)` but are you sure that it is what you want to do ?