# Generic function for changing data.frame column classes not working in R

Tags: r, function, class, dataframe

I've seen a number of folks that have written loops or used different packages to change the class of numerous data.frame columns at once (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432566/change-the-column-type-of-data-frame), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680959/convert-type-of-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-at-once) for SO examples), but I wanted to try my own function. The function works fine if I go line by line, but when I run the function nothing actually happens (i.e., the classes don't actually change). However, I don't get any errors either.

Any help in pointing out the issue would be appreciated!

The function:

```
  class.changer <- function(col.names,dat,class.to) {
    for(i in c(col.names)) {
      dat[,i] <- eval(parse(text=paste0('as.',class.to,'(dat[,\'',i,'\'])')))
    }
  }
```

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5)
str(df)
class.changer('a',df,'factor')
str(df) #alas, no change!!
```

Comment: you need to return `dat` and save the results to a variable like any other function as [joran does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680959/convert-type-of-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-at-once/7681273#7681273) for example

Comment: The first answer to the linked duplicate has a good example of the principle enunciated by rawr.